# angular 7 deployment on android, is cordova necessary?

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I have an angular 7 project deployment which runs fine on apache. I like to 
use it on android app. After some study, a server like cordova is necessary
for android platform. nativescript is also an option. I really like not to 
have cordova bundled in android app. Is it true that I can not use angular 7
deployment directly on webview app? I have several app run on angularjs 1.x which
is working great.

any comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Cordova is *NOT* needed and you can easily use your Angular deployment inside the webview of
>   android/iOS app.

Cordova is not a server, but it provides the below

- CLI to create and manage android/iOS projects and also generate the apk/ipa (app binary). So, with your angular depoyment, you can generate both iOS and android app with single CLI.
- These created projects uses webview internally, so all your HTML resources are rendered inside webview.
- Plugins interface to communicate with native modules. There are plugins available for [automated codepush](https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push) too.

Finally, if you can maintain your android/iOS app yourself, and all you want is just rendering your HTML app inside webview, you do not need Cordova.

Comment: I just tried but I got a blank screen on emulator. Is android chrome capable to handle angluar route? I have some route in app and read some issue about angular route on android.

Comment: Inspect your webview with chrome (`chrome://inspect`) and look for errors. Most of them is self explanatory. It may not work out of the box.